# camera plus photo captured event is not working

Tags: nativescript

I'm trying to include camera plus plugin into my  project. but i'm not getting why photo captured event was not triggering.

I have worked on it and created a playground sample where photo captured event was not working.

https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=7sKw5q

```
exports.onLoaded = function (args) {
  console.log(`onLoaded`);

  let cam = page.getViewById("camPlus");

  cam.on(CameraPlus.photoCapturedEvent, (event) => {
    photoCapturedEvent(event);
  });
}


exports.photoCapturedEvent = function (e) {
  console.log('-----------------photo captured !---------------------');
  console.log(e.data.android); // the path of the captured file, eg. "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/COM.YOURAPP.NAME/files/IMG_1535045496885.jpg"

  try {
    const imageFromLocalFile = imageSourceModule.fromFile(e.data.android);
    console.log('-----------------imageFromLocalFile !---------------------');
    console.log(imageFromLocalFile);

    let filePhoto = fileSystemModule.File.fromPath(e.data.android);

    console.log('-----------------filePhoto !---------------------');
    console.log(filePhoto);
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log("Error: " + err);
  }
};
```

need to know whats the issue. whether my code is wrong or something else

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the method under `exports.photoCapturedEvent` but you are calling it with just `photoCapturedEvent`.

```
cam.on(CameraPlus.photoCapturedEvent, (event) => {
  exports.photoCapturedEvent(event);
});
```

[Updated Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=7sKw5q&v=2)

Comment: but still i'm not getting any console. i have tried all the possibilities calling only plain function and exports function and photoCapturedEvent is not working. kindly have a look at console messages which i have included in code. this solution still didn't answered the question.

Comment: I see photo captured event on console.

Comment: can you confirm are you using IOS or Androd. i used android and i'm not able to get the console with the code updated by you.

Comment: It's Android only, the plugin do not work on iOS with Playground as it requires external POD libraries.

Comment: i dont know whats wrong with my mobile. i have tried it on playground and on vscode either case i'm not getting photocaptured event. but all other events are working fine. is their any specific android version required for this. or anything else is needed ?

Comment: i checked github demo also, except photocaptured event all was working fine. anyone facing the same problem can upvote this issue.